# How to manually revalidate / trigger validation using unobtrusive jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have created my own conditional validation attribute to validate my MVC model on both the client and the server by inheriting from `RequiredAttribute` and implementing `IClientValidatable`. The idea is that if a boolean property on my model is true, then another property is required. In the view this manifests itself as a checkbox which dictates whether a  textbox needs to be filled in.

This works perfect except for when the user performs the following actions:

- Checks the checkbox (the field is now required).
- Submits the form (client side validation runs, error message displayed).
- User unchecks box (error message remains, field no longer required).

I would like to revalidate the form when the checkbox is checked or unchecked, or even better just revalidate that field, so that the error message is no longer displayed. I have tried various combinations of calling the jQuery `validate()` method, but nothing seems to be able to re-run validation.

I use the following javascript to set up my validation function and the associated unobtrusive adapter.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "requiredif",
    function(value, element, parameters) {
        var selector = "#" + parameters["dependentpropertyname"];
        var triggerValue = parameters["triggervalue"].toString().toLowerCase();
        var actualValue = $(selector).is(":checked").toString().toLowerCase();
        if (actualValue === triggerValue) return $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);

        return true;
    });

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    "requiredif",
    ["dependentpropertyname", "triggervalue"],
    function(options) {
        options.rules["requiredif"] = {
            dependentpropertyname: options.params["dependentpropertyname"],
            triggervalue: options.params["triggervalue"]
        };
        options.messages["requiredif"] = options.message;
    }
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to revalidate a datepicker field using jquery validate and jquery ui.  [This post](http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/validating_the_jquery_ui_datepicker) helped me figure it out.

The key, is just add a callback to the valid method for that selector. Something like:

```
$(".requiredif").change(function() {
  $(this).valid();
})
```

Answer (score -5):

You should check out [Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/). It does what you are trying to do without you having to roll your own.

Comment: That looks great! Thanks for the link, but I still have the same problem. I.e. how to revalidate/trigger validation on the client for all or part of my form?

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP has asked how to peel and orange and you've answered by saying you should eat an apple instead. Could possibly be a comment.