# preventing immediate submission after modal popoup

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, modal-dialog

validation for my form is done on the server-side so it only fires when the user submits the form. I wish to display a modal popup summarizing the data the user just entered and give them the option to continue or cancel. As of right now, the modal displays for a second and then it goes on to save without waiting for user confirmation. How can i keep the form from submitting until the user decides to do so?

form:

```
    <div id="Display" class="fieldset">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("AddAccount", "RxCard", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Add", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {

                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form">
                            <label id="lblAccountName">Account Name</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pharmacy.AccountName, null, new { @class = "validationmessage" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.AccountName )

                            <label style="margin: 5px" id="lblAddress">Address</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pharmacy.Address, null, new { @class = "validationmessage" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.Address)

                            <label style="margin: 5px" id="lblCity">City</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pharmacy.City, null, new { @class = "validationmessage" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.City)

                            <label style="margin: 5px" id="lblState">State</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pharmacy.State, null, new { @class = "validationmessage" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.State)

                            <label style="margin: 5px" id="lblZip">Zip</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pharmacy.ZipCode, null, new { @class = "validationmessage" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.ZipCode)

                            <label style="margin: 5px" id="lblPhoneNumber">Phone Number (optional)</label>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.Area, new {  @onkeyup = "tabout(this,'Pharmacy_Prefix');", @maxlength = "3", @style = "float:left; width:5em" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.Prefix, new { @onkeyup = "tabout(this,'Pharmacy_Suffix');", @maxlength = "3", @style = "float:left; width:5em" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.Suffix, new { @maxlength = "4", @style = "float:left; width:5em" })

                            <input type="hidden" id="IgnoreDuplicate" name="IgnoreDuplicate" /> 
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <button type="submit" value="Save" name="AddNew" id="AddNew" data-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                    <button type="submit" value="Cancel">Cancel</button> 
                }               
            </div>   
        </section>
       //modal
        <div id="dialog-modal" class="dialog-modal-style">
            <div>
                confirm details
            </div>
            <div>
            Are you sure you want to submit the following account?
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Account Name</th>
                    <td id="Name"></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <td id="Address"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <td id="City"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <td id="State"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Zip Code</th>
                    <td id="Zip"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("AddNew").onclick = function OpenDialog() {

    var address = $("#Pharmacy_Address").val();
    var Name = $("#Pharmacy_AccountName").val();
    var City = $("#Pharmacy_City").val();
    var State = $("#Pharmacy_State").val();
    var Zip = $("#Pharmacy_ZipCode")
    $("#City").text($('#Pharmacy_City').val());
    $("#State").text($('#Pharmacy_State').val());
    $("#Name").text($('#Pharmacy_AccountName').val());
    $("#Address").text($('#Pharmacy_Address').val());
    $("#Zip").text($('#Pharmacy_ZipCode').val());

    if (Zip && State && Name && address && City != "") {
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog({         
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            draggable: true,
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: 'dialog-modal-style',
            buttons: {
                "Add this account": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close")
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close")
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: This sort of thing is usually done by using `type='button'` instead of `type='submit'` and manually calling `form.submit()` in the button click handlers

Comment: @Tibrogargan the issue is that the modal only shows after the fields have passed validation. Changing the type and adding the line in KhalidT 's answer will take care of everything but will not trigger validation. Or am i just not understanding what you're trying to say?

Comment: See [this](/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation) (Your question quite literally says validation is done on the server - so I was assuming you weren't validating on the client)

Comment: Ok, so .. looking more closely at your code I realize you're using asp.net-mvc, which is inserting all sorts of validation code into your web page.  Your actually doing a lot of validation on the client and perhaps the server also.  It seems like perhaps the validation you're talking about is being generated by asp.net-mvc before the form is ever sent to the server.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533656/how-to-manually-revalidate-trigger-validation-using-unobtrusive-jquery-validat) may help

Comment: I would suggest you to submit the form or data entered in the form to controller after clicking on Continue.On click of Submit u show summary of details entered on the modal popup

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the **AddNew** button from **submit** to **button** and add the following line to the **Add this account** button's callback function in your modal dialog to submit the form manually:

```
document.getElementById("Add").submit();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **event.preventDefault()**, which restrict button submit call

```
$('#AddNew').click(function(event){    

event.preventDefault();

var address = $("#Pharmacy_Address").val();
var Name = $("#Pharmacy_AccountName").val();
var City = $("#Pharmacy_City").val();
var State = $("#Pharmacy_State").val();
var Zip = $("#Pharmacy_ZipCode")
$("#City").text($('#Pharmacy_City').val());
$("#State").text($('#Pharmacy_State').val());
$("#Name").text($('#Pharmacy_AccountName').val());
$("#Address").text($('#Pharmacy_Address').val());
$("#Zip").text($('#Pharmacy_ZipCode').val());

if (Zip && State && Name && address && City != "") {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({         
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'dialog-modal-style',
        buttons: {
            "Add this account": function () {
                $("#Add").submit();//Call form submit 
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```