# how to get validation by using e.preventDefault(); MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

when I click `SaveCompany` button the validation is not because of `e.preventDefault();` so how to do validation by using `e.preventDefault();`

```
$("#SaveCompany").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    GetInfo();
});
```

Form

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="section-header">
            <div class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl-row">
                    <div class="tbl-cell">
                        <h2>Company Registration Form</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddCompany", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <section class="tabs-section">
                <div class="tabs-section-nav tabs-section-nav-icons">
                    <div class="tbl">
                        <ul class="nav" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" href="#tabs-1-tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="font-icon font-icon-cogwheel"></i>
                                        Company Registration Form
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#tabs-1-tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
                                        Company Social Network
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#tabs-1-tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>
                                        Company Reference
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--.tabs-section-nav-->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="tabs-1-tab-1">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <section>
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-label semibold control-label" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtCompanyName", placeholder = "Enter the Company Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.CompanyName)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.ShortName, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.ShortName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtShortName", placeholder = "Enter the Short Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.ShortName)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Division, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Division, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtDivision", placeholder = "Enter the Division" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Division)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Contact Person</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.ContactPerson, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtContactPerson", placeholder = "Enter the Contact Person Name" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Designation, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Designation, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtDesignation", placeholder = "Enter the Designation" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Email, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtEmail", placeholder = "Enter your Email" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Email)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Address Line 1</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Address1, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtAddress1", placeholder = "Enter your Address Line 1" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Address1)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Address Line 2</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Address2, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtAddress2", placeholder = "Enter your Address Line 2" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Country, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.DropDownList("Country", null, "--- Select Country ---", new { @class = "select2-arrow" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.State, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            <select id="state" class="select2-arrow"></select>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Location / City</label>
                                            @*<select id="city" class="select2-arrow"></select><br />*@
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.City, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtCity", placeholder = "Enter your Location / City" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Pincode / ZipCode</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Pincode, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPincode", placeholder = "Enter your Pincode" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Pincode)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Country Code</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.CountryCode, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtCountryCode", placeholder = "Enter your Country Code" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Mobile Number</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.MobileNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtMobileNo", placeholder = "Enter your Mobile Number" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.MobileNo)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Phone Number</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.PhoneNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPhoneNo", placeholder = "Enter your PhoneNo" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">PAN Number</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.PanNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPanNo", placeholder = "Enter Company PanNo" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Tin Number</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.TinNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTinNo", placeholder = "Enter Company TinNo" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">GST Number</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.GSTno, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtGSTno", placeholder = "Enter Company GSTno" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.IECCode, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.IECCode, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtIECCode", placeholder = "Enter Company IECCode" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Upload Company Logo</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <input type="file" name="ImageFile" id="txtUploadImage" style="cursor:pointer;" />
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label semibold">Perview Image</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <img id="image_upload_preview" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="your image" />
                                            <a id="remove" onclick="javascript:ClearFileUploadControl();" style="display: none; cursor: pointer;">Remove</a>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="SaveCompany" value="Save" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
                            </div>
                        </section>

                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-1-tab-2">
                        <br />
                        <section>
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.FaceBookID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.FaceBookID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtFaceBookID", placeholder = "Enter the Facebook Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.TwitterID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.TwitterID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTwitterID", placeholder = "Enter the Twitter Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.linkedinID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.linkedinID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtlinkedinID", placeholder = "Enter the Linkedin Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Previous" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary prev-step " />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="saveSocial" value="Next" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-1-tab-3">
                        Tab 3
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Previous" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary prev-step" />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Finish" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                </div><!--.tab-content-->
            </section><!--.tabs-section-->
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use `form.submit()` instead of button click

Comment: What's the reason you are using `preventDefault()`?

Comment: yes sir @JustCode

Comment: stop for page load when i click button @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: Do you mean that clicking `#saveCompany` should just execute validation and call `GetInfo()` without submitting the form? If it's the case then it should not be an input of `type='submit'` but a simple button, to trigger validation just use `$('#id-of-your-form').valid()`

Comment: yes sir my problem has been cleared @AdrianoRepetti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some related posts, below.

They both point to calling the valid method on the element or form, depending on what level you want to trigger validation.

For example, if your form had an id:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCompany", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
```

Then to validate by that form's id:

```
$('#myForm').valid()
```

Valid will apparently perform the validation and then also return the result of if the form or element is valid.

[Call MVC 3 Client Side Validation Manually for ajax posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127813/call-mvc-3-client-side-validation-manually-for-ajax-posts)

[How to manually revalidate / trigger validation using unobtrusive jQuery validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533656/how-to-manually-revalidate-trigger-validation-using-unobtrusive-jquery-validat)

Answer (score 1):

Hold the form submit like:

```
$('#formId').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

check all the fields for valid value. If valid, submit the form, otherwise show the error messages.